# rspec-rails and using let leading to variable conflicts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Was writing some tests and ran into an issue with using `let` to define some variables.

I spent some time producing a minimal failing example:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "Some behavior" do
  let(:attachments_dir) { "some_test_dir" }

  before :all do
    attachments_dir  # Commenting out this line makes the tests pass
  end

  context "nested 1" do
    let(:api_params) do
      { message: { to: "recipient1", from: "sender1"} }
    end

    before do
      puts "nested 1 before " + api_params.to_s
    end

    it "nested 1 example 1" do
      api_params[:message][:to].should == "recipient1"
    end
  end

  context "nested 2" do
    let(:api_params) do
      { message: { from: "sender2"} }
    end

    before do
      puts "nested 2 before " + api_params.to_s
    end

    it "nested 2 example 1" do
      api_params[:message][:to].should be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

This test fails

```
nested 1 before {:message=>{:to=>"recipient1", :from=>"sender1"}}
nested 2 before {:message=>{:to=>"recipient1", :from=>"sender1"}}

expected: nil
   got: "recipient1"
```

However, commenting out line #8 of the example causes the test to pass

```
#attachments_dir
```

Why would the top level `let` interfere with the nested context `let`s? This feels like a RSpec bug to me, but I figured I'd ask here before posting to their issues list.

Comment: What version of RSpec are you using? Ensure it's the latest.

Comment: It's a little odd that you are calling `attachments_dir` in a before all block. If you want to eagerly define something, you can use `let!`

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - I'm using the latest version - explicitly updated to latest before I posted

Comment: @aubreyrhodes - The example here is simplified and hence looks contrived. In the real code I'm actually doing something more interesting with the variable
Thanks for letting me know about let! though

Comment: This is surprising behavior. I'd urge you to pursue this as a potential bug. btw removing the `before(:all)` and changing `let(:attachments_dir)` to `let!` seems to fix it.

Comment: For anyone interested in this, I've logged a rspec-rails issue

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/626