# let() value cached across examples when before(:all) is used?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I have a spec file which looks like:

```
# foo_spec.rb
class Foo
end

describe Foo do
  let(:foo) { 'foo' }
  subject { bar }

  # before(:all) { foo } # The seond example fails if uncomment this line.

  describe 'test one' do
    let(:bar) { 'one' }
    it        { should == 'one' }
  end

  describe 'test two' do
    let(:bar) { 'two' }
    it        { should == 'two' }
  end
end
```

Both examples are passing as expected. However, if I un-comment the before(:all), the second example fails:

```
1) Foo test two
     Failure/Error: it        { should == 'two' }
       expected: "two"
            got: "one" (using ==)
```

AFAIK, the value of let() will be cached across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples. So not quite sure why it fails the second example when the before(:all) is used.

I'm using ruby 1.9.2p180 and rspec 2.6.4

Comment: In general, using `before(:all)` is a terrible idea that causes lots of pain and problems.

Comment: +1. There's momentum to kill it entirely: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/573

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906268/rspec-rails-and-using-let-leading-to-variable-conflicts

Answer (score 5):

This is [a known problem](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/500) with rspec:

> `let`s are not designed to be used with `before(:all)` blocks

([Quoting](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/656#issuecomment-7380798) rspec contributor myronmarston from [yet another ticket](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/656) on the issue (which seems quite similar to the behavior you're describing here)).